# When using sublime text 2, how can I have the built executable run in terminal?

Tags: c++, c, sublimetext2

I am using sublime text under Ubuntu. As every sublime text user knows, we can build from a .cpp file in sublime using *Tools->Build*, and run it using *Tools->Run*. This is really convenient!

The problem is the executable can only run inside a local window at the bottom of sublime, without the ability to interactively accept user's input.

I changed the cmd line in **C++.sublimetext** as this:

```
"cmd": ["x-terminal-emulator","-e", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'   
&& '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
```

Although typing

> "x-terminal-emulator -e executable_file_path_and_name"

in a terminal does work, it failed in sublime. Is this a bug in sublime?

Any way to make it run in a terminal?

Comment: what error did you get when it failed?

Comment: @MattDMo In fact, the terminal did appear for about maybe several ms, and disappeared so fast that I even can't see clearly the content of it.  Besides, it seemed that it's just a blank terminal, no matter what should appear in it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the terminal program closes as soon as your compiler or C++ program quits (and since the compiler also quits after failed compilation, you'll never see any error messages). And also because the terminal doesn't know how to handle `&&`.

Use this:

```
"cmd": ["x-terminal-emulator","-e", 
  "bash -c \"g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' ; read -p 'Press any key to continue...'\""],
```

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 3 now. It's not convenient to modify C++.sublimetext in ST3, so I can't test it now. Hope others can test it.